# Excel Find & Replace Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which imports all of my orders, however when creating labels, I only have a limited amount of space for the title. I'm using a Find & Replace Macro in Excel which looks in my current active imported worksheet, and replaces with text from another worksheet which I use as a table with 2 columns, Column A is what the title is when imported and Column B is what I want to change it to. This script works perfectly fine except it doesn't find columns that have a different beginning. For example:

Imported Worksheet:

Entry 1: BANANAS

Entry 2: 30 X BANANAS

Table:

Column A: BANANAS

*Column B: Yellow Bananas*

//Script Runs//

Output:
Imported Worksheet:

*Entry 1: Yellow Bananas*

**Entry 2: 30 X BANANAS**

As you can see in the example above, the "30 X BANANAS" entry does not change to "30 X Yellow Bananas", as I would want it to. I'm guessing I need to add a wildcard line of code to my script below, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it?

```
Sub FindReplace()
  Dim s As String
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Range("H3:H5000").Cells
    If cell <> "" Then
      ans = Application.VLookup(cell, Sheets("Script").Range("A1:B1000"), 2, 0)
      If Not IsError(ans) Then cell = ans
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [Range.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086%28v=office.15%29.aspx) function rather than the VLookup function, you will get the result you are looking for.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

```
Sub FindNReplace()
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

'Set Range Values
Set InputRng = Range("A1:A5")
Set ReplaceRng = Sheets("Script").Range("A1:B100")

'Spin through replacement range and perform replace
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
    InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
End Sub
```